# Levi-Civita tensor

Tags: tensor-calculus, matrix-elements

The Kronecker delta can be represented by a two dimensional matrix:

\begin{gather}
\delta_{ij}=\mathbb{I}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&1\\
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{gather}

Similarly, can the Levi-Civita tensor
\begin{gather}
\epsilon_{ijk}
\end{gather}
be represented by a three dimensional matrix, and if so, what does the matrix look like?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Yes.

Comment: Wow!  Short comment for a short question!  Make a sandwich pile of three antisymmetric matrices.  Three different antisymmetric matrices :  one of bread, one of cheese, and one of peanut butter!  ;-)

Comment: I'm reasonably certain that the Wikipedia entry in the LC tensor had exactly what you're looking for...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Wikipedia:

> [image]

It might be a little messy, but imagine the layers as having the $i$ index, the rows having the $j$ index, and the columns having the $k$ index.

Chiefly, the Levi-Civita Tensor gives $1$ for cyclic permutations and $-1$ for anti-cyclic permutations. In the image above, the front most layer (blue) has index $i=1$. Hence, the indices in the layer is ${1,j,k}$.

For the cyclic combination ${1,2,3}$, that is, at layer $1$, row $2$, column $3$, the value is $1$. Similarly, for the anti-cyclic combination ${1,3,2}$, the value is $-1$ appears at layer $1$, row $3$, column $2$. There are repeats indices in other rows and columns combinations in this layer, and hence the other values are $0$ in this layer.

Similar arguments can be done for the middle layer (red), i.e. for indices ${2,j,k}$ and for the back most layer (green), i.e. for indices ${3,j,k}$, which is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: That was extremely helpful, because the current version of the Wikipedia article doesn't make the it clear which direction j and k pertain to.